# Which tool is getting used by Magento to audit our codes for putting in Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, marketplace

We have tried using php code sniffer but still getting failed at Marketplace? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: They provide you test report.  All details are provide in email.  Follow instructions. Do changes as they wants. Remove unnecessary information and give only important information.

Comment: Try with this https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard

Comment: @ChiragParmar I wanna test before sending my code for audit. So I don't wanna wait until they give me the report

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Thanks, I will check it, Also, I have tried phpcs and phpcpd already.